# Interaction trigger does not let property changed event to fire

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, pivot, interaction, selectedindex

My question is why I am seeing some unexpected behaviour when using an interaction trigger and not when using an ordinary click event.

In my WP7 app I have a pivot control with three pivot items.
On the first pivot item there is a button which does something and then needs to set the current pivot item to display the last one.
I am using MVVM and Prism amongst other tools.

The View is thus:

```
 <controls:Pivot Name="myPivot" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=PivotIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
    <Button Content="Search">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding myViewModel.SearchCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"/>
             </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
  </controls:PivotItem>
   <controls:PivotItem Header="second"></controls:PivotItem>
   <controls:PivotItem Header="third"></controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

And the ViewModel is thus:

```
public class myViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private int mPivotIndex;
    public int PivotIndex
    {
        get { return mPivotIndex; }
        set
        {
            mPivotIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PivotIndex);
        }
    }
    public DelegateCommand SearchCommand { get; set; }
    public myViewModel() 
    {
        this.SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => OnSearch());
    }

    public void OnSearch()
    {
        //do something
        this.PivotIndex = 2;            
    }
}
```

All this works fine, the pivot displays, the button fires the event and the OnSearch() method is called, the property has the value changed.

However the pivot display does not change to show pivot item named 'third'.

I fiddled around for ages and eventually discovered that if I remove the Interaction trigger and changed the View to this:

```
 <Button Content="Search" Click="Search_Click" />
```

And added code behind thus:

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{ ((myViewModel)this.DataContext).OnSearch(); }
```

then everything worked perfectly.

This is a bit unsatisfactory as I like to keep the same approach to command events on all pages, and this is different. But after being stumped by this behaviour for so long, I am just happy to have found something that works finally.

But I'd still like to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this may be something related to threading... try the following and see if this solves the problem:

```cs
public void OnSearch()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        this.PivotIndex = 2;
    });
}
```

Comment: But after looking around, I agree, it is something to do with threading. Just that I am trying to understand why.